# PHP/Linux time issue

Tags: php, linux, datetime, dst

If I run this code on my local server:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

then I get the correct time. However if I run it on my client's dev server then it shows one hour earlier. It's like my client's server thinks it's on standard time instead of daylight saving time.

What could be causing this issue?

Edit:

The output of `zdump -v America/Los_Angeles | grep 2018` is:

```
America/Los_Angeles  Sun Mar 11 09:59:59 2018 UTC = Sun Mar 11 01:59:59 2018 PST isdst=0 gmtoff=-28800
America/Los_Angeles  Sun Mar 11 10:00:00 2018 UTC = Sun Mar 11 03:00:00 2018 PDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-25200
America/Los_Angeles  Sun Nov  4 08:59:59 2018 UTC = Sun Nov  4 01:59:59 2018 PDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-25200
America/Los_Angeles  Sun Nov  4 09:00:00 2018 UTC = Sun Nov  4 01:00:00 2018 PST isdst=0 gmtoff=-28800
```

Comment: The server may not be up to date with dst information. What is the result of `zdump -v America/Los_Angeles | grep 2018`?

Comment: I put the output of `zdump` in the post.

Comment: What do you see if you run the `date` command from shell on the server.

Comment: If I run `date` at 6:15pm pacific it says `Fri Aug 31 17:15:16 PDT 2018`. So the time's simply wrong. Should I change the time using `date` or is there something more I should do?

Comment: @Ryan time should be set to a time server, using ntp protocol. Check `man ntpdate`, specifically how to set, and perhaps point it to `time.nist.gov`

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that you need to check how the time is set on the operating system itself.

[This website](http://solidlystated.com/scripting/php-timezone-settings-and-dst/) provides the following tip:

> Remember, first and foremost PHP gets it time from the operating system. You must correctly set the time, timezone, and DST settings for your operating system or PHP will not display the correct time, no matter what calculations you are doing in your script.

Comment: A shocking number of people turn off NTP and then incorrectly adjust their time without regard for the timezone. `=_=`